# Help needed wiring a bathroom fan/vent combo

Tags: wiring, bathroom, fans

We had a bathroom rewired some time ago. The electrician who did it is away for the cold months. So I’ve set off trying to wire up our new fan/light combo so we can get the ceiling up.  I’m also wanting to add a dual switch in place of the single switch.

Where the fan is mounted in the ceiling there are two wires. One going to the switch box and one I’ve traced to the gfi on the wall. That outlet splices to I believe the other adjacent bathroom. I was able to get the double switch to work but there’s no power going to the adjacent bathroom or gfi which is in the bathroom with the fan I’m installing.

My question is how should the new fan/light be wired? Is it considered a loop?

The wire coming from the gfi is w/b/ground. The wire going to the switch is black/red(pink)/white and ground.

This is how it was wired to a temporary light. [image] The black and ground were capped I just removed them and then snapped the photo.

I appreciate any and all help. I of course will call an electrician if need be. Just thought I’d try it first.

Comment: missing information, Picture of the GFCI wiring, picture of the wall switch wiring,

Comment: "I’ve set off trying to wire up our new fan/light combo so we can get the ceiling up" You do realize that you can't connect wires and then bury those connections behind the ceiling? The wires should be in a junction box and be accessible once the ceiling is up. It doesn't look like those wires are in a junction box and maybe because it's temporary.

Comment: We'll need pictures of each of the wiring spots in question, identifying which cable is which and where it runs to be able to help you out here. Please [edit] that into your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to DIY here.  The mistake was failing to sort this all out before making changes.

Basically, you need to trace more of those cables.  And note we call them cables.  The individual conductors are the wires.

Until you know which cable connects the other bathroom, you won't really know what you're doing.  And we can't tell you how to make the other bathroom work based on a photo of a temporary light.

My best advice is to start with the GFI.  You said there is a cable going from the fan to the GFI and now the GFI is off.  If you're lucky, the other bathroom is connected through the GFI as you suspect and there's only one splice missing now.

> I was able to get the double switch to work

So this is the main problem.  We have no info about what you did to that switch.  It's very likely that you've now got a switched GFI and a switched 2nd bathroom and the wrong cables for a fan/light combo.